# Is it bad for an RF amplifier to leave it on with no input?

Tags: amplifier, rf

I work in a physics lab where we have some inaccessible experiments. One of them involves an RF power amplifier (a ZHL-32A+ from Minicircuits) driving a 50Ohm load that we can't access, but we can control its signal.

Sometime we have to leave this for long periods (~months) not in use. When we're doing this, is it better for the amplifier's aging to leave it with no input RF or with the normal signal? We don't have the option to turn its power off fully.

Comment: The main thing is don't leave it with its **output** not terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These amplifiers (especially from minicircuits) are definitely designed for 24/7 usage throughout years. So, as long as you cool it sufficient (and radiation might be enough, considering it comes in a package including a large heatsink), you should be fine for decades.

If you can control the signal going in: simply don't put in any signal, but e.g. terminate the input with a 50Ω terminator¹. That will minimize power consumption and thus heatup.

---

the terminator of the passive component type, not of the Sarah Connor type.

Comment: +1, glad you clarified which kind of terminator to use :)

Comment: I'll be back.\$\$

Comment: Thanks @Marcus. If I instead left the input floating how does this compare? Is the amplifier now trying to amplify a load of pickup, or is the input impedance usually enough to damp this out?

Comment: well, nothing terrible will happen, but you have to realize you are not letting something "float", you're leaving open the end of a waveguide, in other words, you're allowing the device to pick of ambient noise and act as a (bad) antenna.